# How to align two tables with different columns

Tags: html, html-table

I'm making a responsive site, which has two tables that are aligned vertically. 
The structure is as follows:

```
[         title of table 1          ]
[       col1      ][       col2     ]

[         title of table 2          ]
[  col1  ][  col2  ][ col3 ][ col4  ]
```

The title rows use `colspan="4"` and this table layout works on everything but ios.

When this table is checked on an iphone, the layout looks something like this:

```
[   title of table 1   ]
[   col1   ][   col2   ]

[         title of table 2          ]
[  col1  ][  col2  ][ col3 ][ col4  ]
```

Is there any way to make them the same width on all devices?

I have tried setting the table widths to the same value in pixels, and have been trying to set cell widths as well. Haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: Can you post your html code please?

Comment: Should you be using tables here?  ie are you only using them for layout purposes - if so, then you shouldn't be using a table.  Anyway, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina I can't post the html code for this set as its a work thing.

Comment: @Jerome, then you will not get any help - you could post code with lorem ipsum or dummy data